# Command for replace nth symbol in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to write command in Vim which can delete 9th and 11th symbols in third line. I did this `3s/.{9,11}//` but it did not work. It would be grateful to do this with your suggestions.
Here is an example. I have three lines

> three metres above the sea
>
> three metres below the sea
>
> need some help in vim

So I want to delete 9th symbol in third line which is "e" letter in word "some" and 11th symbol which is letter "h" in word "help".

Comment: For vim, many of the regex operators require backslash escapes.  And %c is the match column op.  `3s/\%9c.//` will replace the any character at column 9 with nothing.

Comment: You can also concatenate substitutions. In this case, position 11 will drop down to 10 after the first change so `:3s/\%9c.//|s/\%10c.//`

Comment: it is a cool solution!!how can I do this command twice? I mean I want to replace any character at  column 9 and at column 11 in one command.

Comment: yep see the cross post.  :-)

Comment: [Record](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#complex-repeat) an operation that does what you need: `qq3G9|x10|xq` then repeat the operation with `@q` or repeat it e.g. 3 times with `3@q`.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  Brian Tiffin! I see now:) My problem is completely resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Moved a comment to an answer*

For Vim, many of the regex specials require backslash escapes.  %c is the column match op.  So

```
:3s/\%9c.//
```

will replace the "any character" at position 9 with nothing.  You can also concatenate substitutions, but things will change between each expression.  In this case, after deleting column 9, 11 (the 'h' in help) would actually be at position 10.

```
:3s/\%9c.//|s/\%10c.//
```

Answer (score 4):

only for the 3rd line:

```
:3norm! 9|x10|x
```

or

```
:norm! 3G9|x10|x
```

Apply on whole buffer:

```
:%norm! 9|x10|x
```

Comment: I got the answer credits, but thank you, Kent. And now, being old, referencing a long gone TV show along with my oft-used valediction. Cheers, Norm!